# CSS3 height transition on DOM removal?

Tags: css, css-transitions

Please check the following fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tWUVe/

When you click the `div`, the `p`'s get deleted, and I expect that the `div`'s height will be animted, but no animation happens. How can I achieve an animation with CSS3 only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that there is no opportunity for the transition to occur. What I mean by this is that when elements are removed, they are immediately taken out of the document flow, resizing the parent if needed without a transition.

As a fix for this, you could animate the height of the paragraphs instead (or a similar means)

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var $thisDiv = $(this);
    $thisDiv.find('p').css({'height':'0px','margin':'0px'}); // Change p height

    // Remove after transition
    setTimeout(function() { $thisDiv.find('p').remove(); }, 1000); 
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/tWUVe/1/)